# Apache 2 using Include with full path

Tags: apache-2.2, windows, configuration

I'm attempting to set up a test environment where the software is being developed on host machines then tested in a Virtual Machine and the VM has all code mapped to a `Z:/` drive. My issue is that Apache is complaining and won't start up saying that I have an invalid `Include` path of Z:/source/myconf.conf. Anyone have luck previously of setting conf files up in a different different drive path that can help me understand what I'm doing wrong? I've tried with and without quotes as well.

Include path statement:

```
Include "Z:/source/myconf.conf"
```

Answers to additional questions:

Z is a virtual drive through VMWare also known as `\\vmware-host`

The specific error in the Application logs is as follows:

```
The Apache service named  reported the following error:
httpd.exe: Syntax error on .. of C:/.../httpd.conf: Invalid Include path Z:/source/myconf.conf
```

Comment: What kind of drive is Z:?

Comment: What is the exact error message in the error log ?

Comment: Added answers to your questions

Answer (score 0):

Try `Include //vmware-host/sharedDriveOrFolderName/source/myconf.conf`

For VirtualBox `Include //VBOXSVR/virtualBoxSharedFolderName/yourLocation/myconf.conf`

Answer (score 0):

Map drives are a per-user configuration, you should use the UNC path, or map the drive as that user (cmd run-as)

1) use the UNC path (igor's answer should suffice)

2) map Z for apache

If you don't have a password set for your service user, you'll need one.

```
runas /noprofile /user:domain_computer\apacheuser cmd
net use Z: \\server\share /user PA$$W0RD
```